# Show that $T(\partial \mathbb{H^n} \cap U)=\partial \mathbb{H^n} \cap V$ where T is a $C^1$ diffeomorphism

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $U$ and $V$ be open subsets of $\mathbb{H^n}$ and $T: U \to V$ be a $C^1$ Diffeomorphism. Show that $T(\partial \mathbb{H^n} \cap U)=\partial \mathbb{H^n} \cap V$.
where $\mathbb{H^n}=\{x \in \mathbb{R^n}|x_1 \le 0 \}$ and let $\partial \mathbb{H^n}=\{x \in \mathbb{H}|x_1=0\}$ be its boundary.

My try:

Let $x \in \partial \mathbb{H^n} \cap U$. Suppose $T(x) \not \in \partial\mathbb{H^n}$. Then There exists an open set $W$ containing $T(x)$ such that $W \cap \partial\mathbb{H^n}=\emptyset$.

I want to use inverse Function theorem to conclude. But I am not getting a move ahead.

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: What is $\mathbb{H}^n$?

Comment: @AnthonyPeter Yeah. Sorry. Edited